# Video format or MIME type is not supported

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

This is the relevant code to run video:

```
<video id="video" src="videos/clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' controls='controls'>
    Your brwoser doesn't seems to support video tag
</video>
```

This code work fine separately, but when trying to fade it in:

```
function showVideoPlayer(){          
    console.log('video displayed');      
    $("#video").fadeIn('medium');
}
```

it doesn't seems to work and i got this:

[image]

As you can see: `Video format or MIME type is not supported.`

The video container is hidden in css:

```
#video{
    position:fixed;
    border:solid 1px #000000;
    width:654px;
    height:454px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    left:23%;
    top:11%;
    display:none;
}
```

This is the idea, the video container is hidden (`display:none`), when needed, i call the function `showVideoPlayer` to show the video container. However that doesn't work and produce me this error in `FireFox` and a blank screen in Chrome and IE9.

Am i missing something? is the `fadeIn` function seems to get me wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the video works fine separately? Firefox does not support mp4 - you need to support it with a separate webm or ogg/theora video.

Comment: It works fine in chrome and IE9. But yes, in FF doesn't work. However, the problem is not there, why that stop working when i `fadeIn` the video container? Thanx.

Comment: I'm not sure what your exact issue is. Does this jsfiddle work on your browser? http://jsfiddle.net/aSQ5A/

Comment: While your embed method (with a single src) is a standard, the method in TimHayes fiddle is more commonly used (and tested). I'd also suggest wrapping the <video> in a container and fading that instead: http://jsfiddle.net/aSQ5A/1/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Firefox does not support the MPEG H.264 (mp4) format at this time, due to a philosophical disagreement with the closed-source nature of the format.

To play videos in all browsers without using plugins, you will need to host multiple copies of each video, in different formats. You will also need to use an alternate form of the `video` tag, as seen in the JSFiddle from @TimHayes above, reproduced below. Mozilla claims that only mp4 and WebM are necessary to ensure complete coverage of all major browsers, but you may wish to consult the Video Formats and Browser Support heading on [W3C's HTML5 Video page](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) to see which browser supports what formats.

Additionally, it's worth checking out the [HTML5 Video page on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Supported_video_formats) for a basic comparison of the major file formats.

Below is the appropriate `video` tag (you will need to re-encode your video in [WebM](http://www.webmproject.org/tools/) or [OGG](http://www.theora.org/downloads/) formats as well as your existing mp4):

```
<video id="video" controls='controls'>
  <source src="videos/clip.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
  <source src="videos/clip.webm" type="video/webm"/>
  <source src="videos/clip.ogv" type="video/ogg"/>
  Your browser doesn't seem to support the video tag.
</video>
```

**Updated Nov. 8, 2013**

Network infrastructure giant Cisco has announced [plans to open-source an implementation of the H.264 codec](http://blogs.cisco.com/collaboration/open-source-h-264-removes-barriers-webrtc/), removing the licensing fees that have so far proved a barrier to use by Mozilla. Without getting too deep into the politics of it (see following link for that) [this will allow Firefox to support H.264 starting in "early 2014"](https://blog.mozilla.org/blog/2013/10/30/video-interoperability-on-the-web-gets-a-boost-from-ciscos-h-264-codec/). However, as noted in that link, this still comes with a caveat. The H.264 codec is merely for video, and in the MPEG-4 container it is most commonly paired with the closed-source AAC audio codec. Because of this, playback of H.264 video will work, but audio will depend on whether the end-user has the AAC codec already present on their machine.

The long and short of this is that progress is being made, but you still can't avoid using multiple encodings without using a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

**For Ubuntu 14.04**

Just removed the package Oxideqt-dodecs
then install flash or ubuntu restricted extras

and you are good to go!!

Answer (score 0):

FIXED IT!

I was losing my mind over this one. Reset firefox, tried safe mode, removed plugins, debugged using developers tools. All were to no avail and didn't get me any further with getting my online videos back to normal viewing condition. This however did the trick perfectly.

Within Firefox or whatever flavor of Firefox you have(CyberFox being my favorite choice here), simply browse to https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/

VERIFY FIRST that the website detected you're using FireFox and has set your download for the flash player to be for Firefox.

Don't just click download. PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE SAVE YOURSELF the migraine and ALWAYS make sure that the middle section labeled "Optional offer:" is absolutely NOT CHECKED, it will be checked by default so always UNCHECK it before proceeding to download.

After it's finished downloading, close out of Firefox. Run the downloaded setup file As Administrator. It takes only a few seconds or so to complete, so after it's done, open up Firefox again and try viewing anything that was previously throwing this error. Should be back to normal now.

Enjoy!

Comment: Installing Flash is very definitely not the answer. Upgrade to the latest version of Firefox *(and uninstall Flash!)*.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error:

> Video format or MIME type is not supported.

Was due to the [CSP in my .htaccess](https://scotthelme.co.uk/content-security-policy-an-introduction/) that did not allow the content to be loaded. You can check this by opening the browser's console and refreshing the page.

Once I added the domain that was hosting the video in the `media-src` part of that CSP, the console was clean and the video was loaded properly. Example:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; media-src https://myvideohost.domain; script-src 'self'; style-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self'
```