# How do I embed mp4 videos on html?

Tags: html, video, mp4

I want to make a site that has videos, how do I embed mp4 videos on html? I have tried `<embed src="helloworld.mp4">` but it doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: @KomninosK: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878068/video-format-or-mime-type-is-not-supported

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In html5 you can use video tag

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should upload them on a host, then embed them.

> (for example youtube, dailymotion, firedrive, sockshare)

Comment: Of course, upload it on youtube and embed it to your site.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <html>
    <body>

    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
      <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Could you please add more details about the solution you provide?